# jQuery: Flexslider caption not working + extra space on the very left of my page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, caption

Im trying to create a new web design for my project, but im stuck on this slider issue.

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slides/newest.png" />
   <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
   <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DhsuS/5/

1st thing: The slider with captions should look like this: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
but the one that I have doesn't look close to that. Not quite sure what I did wrong. :/

2nd thing: Not sure why there's extra space on the very left of the page, but it might ruin my design, so anyone wanna spot that out.

3rd thing: sometimes, the image is out of place, or the slider is missing, or the image doesn't load at all. Not sure why this keeps happening.

Dont ask about the header, i messed that up, but ill fix it after i get this slider done and over with.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Please post your code, recommend is through [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to set width for slider container
you use -30px left for navigation a tag, and it will place out of page, so you will see the scroll bar in page, if you dont want this sroll and want full page slider you must set

```
.slidercontaier { overflow : hidden; }
```

and also seems you didnt copy all css that needed

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in css:

```
.flex-caption {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 96%;
}
```

remove or comment the background property from that class, this will make your image visible in `li`.
One more thing, either use a exact sized image or update your CSS classes to fit as per your image providing then height and width attributes.

[Click here for Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DhsuS/6/)

Comment: I used a different slider plugin, i think this new one works better. Thanks anyways guys :)